# Sine of infinity?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

While considering limiting problems there are some situations when we have argument tending to infinity of sine or cosine function .

My book writes it as an *"OSCILLATING number between $-1$ & $1$"*.

How is this possible?

Comment: As $x$ become arbitrarily large, we will still see $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ oscillating between $\pm1$. These do not converge. So if you consider $\sin(x)/x$ as $x$ becomes arbitrarily large, you can get some impression on its behavior, knowing how $\sin(x)$ behaves.

Comment: There is no “oscillating number”. I guess your book wants to express the idea that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$ does not exist.

Comment: "oscillating number" is indeed a very poor formulation. $sin$ and $cos$ are "oscillating **functions**" between $-1$ and $+1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is oscilatting between $1$ and $-1$ is the sine (and the cosine). It follows from this that the limit cannot exist.

It's even worst with the tangent function: it keeps oscilatting between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. The conclusion is the same, of course: $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\tan x$ does not exist.

Comment: Is that means that there is no particular single value of it but it keeps changing its value? Or it is a vague expression

Comment: @PranjalRana Saying that the sine keeps oscilatting between $1$ and $-1$ means that, for each real number $R$, there are numbers $x,y\geqslant R$ such that $\sin(x)=1$ and that $\sin(y)=-1$. So it is not a vague expression.

Answer (score 1):

"$\sin \infty$" (informal notation) is not a defined number because the function $\sin x$ is oscillating. For this reason,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sin x$ can takes any value that is inside $[-1,1]$

So, when we say x tends to infinity that means x is getting larger and larger.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\sin x=DNE$$

Visual aid.

[image]

Can you see why the limit does not exist? It is a form of oscillatory series. It oscillates between $-1\leq x\leq 1$. $x\mapsto\infty$ It does not approach any fixed value of y.

Answer (score -1):

I have a slightly more creative and less conventional answer which I personally think is viable if you're not taking a calulus test.

On WolframAlpha if you do sin(infinity) you will get "-1 to 1." I am not sure how they got this answer but I definitely agree with it and here's why.

sin(∞) ?= [-1,1]

first of all, ∞=n+∞ for all n>0 and heres why:

x=n+x

using infinite iterations of recursive substitution we get

x=n+n+n+n+n+⋯

we can rewrite this as

∞

∑ n

i=1

we assume the above sum is equal to ∞ for all n>0, therefore x=∞

therefore ∞=n+∞ for all n>0

heres where we prove that sin(∞)=[-1,1]

if sin(∞)=sin(0)

then sin(∞+90)=sin(0+90)

but since ∞=90+∞,

sin(∞)=sin(0) and sin(90) with the initial assumption sin(∞)=sin(0)

we can extend this to all positive numbers replacing 90 with n

we thus can prove that sin(∞) is the solution set of all possible values for sin(n) where n is any positive number

and since sin(n) can be anything on the interval from -1 <= n <= 1, sin(∞) is all of these values. "all of these values" is [-1,1]

Thanks for reading this goofy proof. I am serious though, I legitimately believe this. This will likely get downvoted for being so unconventional, and since lim(x→∞)[ sin(x) ] does not really approach anything intuitively, I may even be wrong. Tell me what you think, and sorry for all the newline characters that make this answer super long and spaced out.

Comment: That means sine infinity is equal to any possible number between -1 and 1...... However nice

Comment: @PranjalRana exactly. Well, more like its equal to all of them at the same time. Think of ±3. Is it 3 or -3? I say both.